# while loop exiting without condition false

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I don't understand why this code breaks the loop when `tot` is equal or less than 10 and it doesn't when it is more than 10. 
I can't believe I still can't manage this basic thing.. help me please!

```
do {
    tot = 0;
    system("CLS");

    printf("Inserisci 10 sfere tra rosse, blu e verdi");

    printf("\n\n Rosse : ");
    scanf(" %d" , &rosse);  
    tot += rosse;   
    for (i = 0; i < rosse; i++) {
        sfere[i] = 1;
    }

    printf("\n Verdi : ");
    scanf(" %d", &verdi);
    tot += verdi;
    for (i = 0; i < verdi; i++) {
        sfere[i+rosse] = 2;
    }

    printf("\n Blu : ");
    scanf(" %d", &blu);
    tot += blu;
    for (i = 0; i < blu; i++) {
        sfere[i+rosse+verdi] = 3;
    }       

    if (tot == 10) {
        break;
    }
}   while (true);
```

I tried as well doing it like this but i get the same result..

```
while (tot != 10);
```

I underline that i am using `scanf` and `printf` because my university course wants to, to make us understand better how the memory works and keep safe from errors in future.

Comment: Notice the code `if (tot == 10) {
        break;
    }` - That ends the loop when `tot` is 10

Comment: You have not shown the definition of `sfere`, but given the way you index the array by adding multiple indexes together, you may well be over-running the array, and possibly changing the value of `tot` via undefined behavior.

Comment: BTW: not testing the return value of `scanf` is *always* going to bite you.

Comment: @Jens - Getting fed up with typing that as well

Comment: @Jens Ok thank you! I will from now on!
@abelenky i think this could be a problem but the error that made my loop not end was in the code outside the loop and was because i initialized a `srand(time(NULL))` instead of `srand(time(&t))`

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided will only break a while loop when tot is equal to 10

```
if (tot == 10) {
    break;
}
```

The second snippet (the one below) will behave the same however this approach is better since you're explicitely writing the loop should end when tot equals 10 (then condition `tot != 10` will become false which will stop the loop):

```
while (tot != 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're **`tot`** variable is getting arbitrary numbers. It would probably be better to do:

```
if(tot >= 10){
     break
}
```

Unless there is a specific reason that you think **`tot`** will always be 10. Otherwise, you've got an infinite loop if **`tot`** doesn't end up being 10.

An alternative, which would leverage a do{}while() loop would be to do:

```
 do{
      //code
 }while(tot >= 10)
```

Comment: i wanted 10 to be the only possible answer to exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
    // ...
    if (tot == 10) {
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

to this

```
   // ...
} while (tot < 10);
```

because the total might not hit exactly `10`, and because the logic is cleaner and sweeter - notice how I use your required condition to end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! i don't know why my loop was never ending because of some code outside the loop..
It began working when i changed `srand(time(NULL))` with `srand(time(&t))` !!!
(declaring `time_t t;` before.